# rails 5.1.4 ( ActionCable + Jobs + Devise + ConversationsController.render )

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Actually I need a big help, I'm using `rails 5.1.4`, I get stuck when rendering a partial with ActionCable and background Jobs. In my partial, I have a condition on `current_user` to check if `current_user` is the message owner and get his username with green color to make somes differents, so far display an update and delete button for each message he's the owner in the room conversations. But, if I refresh the page or remove `current_user` in the partial before rendering it works. However, I want that condition happens. Or, looking for a best way if there is one. THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Here is the error displayed in my terminal:

```
ERROR: ActionView::Template::Error: Devise could not find the warden::Proxy instance on your request environment.
```

Those are my files content.

The partial: _conversation.html.erb

```
<div id="message"> 
  <% if conversation.user == current_user %>
   <span style="text-align: center; color: green"><%= conversation.user.username %>
   </span>
  <% else %>
   <span style="text-align: center; color: magenta"><%= 
    conversation.user.username %></span>
  <% end %>  
  <p style="color: black"><%= conversation.body %></p>
 </div>
```

Message_controller.rb

```
def create
  conversation = @room.conversations.new(conversation_params)
  conversation.user = current_user
  conversation.save
  MessageRelayJob.perform_later(conversation)    
End
```

Room/show.html

```
 <div id="conversations" data-room-id="<%= @room.id %>">
  <%= render @room.conversations %>
 </div>
```

MY JOB CLASS

```
 class MessageRelayJob < ApplicationJob
   queue_as :default

   def perform(conversation)
     ActionCable.server.broadcast "room_tchats_#{conversation.room.id}_channel",
      conversation: render_conversation(conversation)
   end

   private

   def render_conversation(conversation)
    ConversationsController.render partial: 'conversations/conversation', locals: {conversation: conversation}
   end
 end
```

Comment: doesn't the request.env['warden'] object have to be inserted in the middleware stack - x2 this?

Comment: if you can say more I will very appreciate , so what I want there is to display current_user messages with a different css style to make difference,  like: if current_user is the owner of any message in the tchat,  display those messages to the left or something like that,  and else display to the right side when rendering the message partial.  But if I put a condition on current user in the partial, the error come up. 
If you understand what I mean.

Comment: MessageController create action needs to be ended by end keyword and not End

Comment: @JallohIbrahima I had the same issue before, yet I could not find any answer for it. You question is very good, yet please IMHO, try to have better wordings cuz It is kind of unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @JallohIbrahima look at this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4466

Comment: Pass in your user to the perform method in your job. Your job should only use data that is passed to it.

Answer (score 5):

It can be happening when you try to get Devise `current_user` in some part of code being managed by action cable. like a background job to render comment or something else. you can resolve it by using something like following in your controller, since you cant access warden at a model or job level(according to my limited knowledge): (I call a job right after creation of my comment in CommentsController create action, which calls a private method to render a comment partial containing edit and delete button, for which current_user was required)

```
 def create
@product = Product.find(comment_params[:product_id])
@comment = @product.comments.build(comment_params)
@comment.save!

gon.comment_id = @comment.id
gon.comment_user_id = @comment.user_id

ActionCable.server.broadcast "chat", comment: render_comment

render :create, layout: false
end

def render_comment
  CommentsController.renderer.instance_variable_set(:@env, {"HTTP_HOST"=>"localhost:3000", 
    "HTTPS"=>"off", 
    "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"GET", 
    "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"",   
    "warden" => warden})

  CommentsController.render(
    partial: 'comments/comment_detail',
    locals: {
      product: @product,
      comment: @comment
    }
  )
end
```

this will help you resolve warden issue, if you have used devise's current_user in that partial, it will give you the commentor user (as it should since that user initiated the rendering of partial). Now to solve this, if you have a front end framework you might need to fetch the current user from cookies in order to restrict some actions like edit/delete. but if you are working in pure rails the solution I came across is that you have to make a hidden field in the dom having current users id, and you will fetch that id for comparison in a script. you might need to access rails variables in javascript, for that you can use ***GON*** gem. I know this answer might contain much more than asked but I've searched alot and no where I found a satisfactory solution to this problem, feel free to discuss.